# Is there a way to conceal a URL but have it still be valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've looked at both URLRewriting and Redirecting and I'm mostly convinced it's not the way to go.

What I have is a web form that takes in a search string, and then outputs results as links to different PDF files that are hosted on a web share. These files are not local or apart of the web forms at all. When you click a link to a pdf you get the direct web link to the pdf, for example:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/portfolios/employees/evaluations/test1.pdf
```

If a user gets that link and backspaces to:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/portfolios/employees
```

They could potentially have access to all other records. The example is a little bad because I can't apply explicit permissions to the page at hand. So what I'd like to know if it's somehow possible to re-write

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/portfolios/employees/evaluations/test1.pdf
```

to something like

```
http://www.mywbesite.com/test1.pdf
```

and have it still be valid?

Comment: You shouldn't be worried about the URL itself. Instead, you should modify your service to only return files if they're authorized to do so. The best way to do this might be to add a Generic Handler (.ashx) that can verify the user is authorized for the requested file, then writes the file to the response. If they're not authorized, return an error status code.

Comment: Server.Redirect? Although I agree this is a poor way to handle security.

Comment: The problem is everyone is authorized. It's so students and guests can search for the syllabus of a course at a college. The records aren't anything critical like another employee's documents. It's actually fine if the students can get to the link described in my question because all they'll see are ALL the syllabus in a file structure, but, I'd like to get around it if possible.

Comment: You said that they shouldn't have access. That means they are NOT authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a generic handler to your website, lets call it FileRetriever.ashx. This will allow us to use some logic to make sure the user is authorized to access the file they're requesting. This assumes your users have logged into the site (else how will you know whether they are allowed to access the file or not?)

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString["file"]))
        {
        //return error status code telling them to provide a file
        context.Response.End();
        }

    string requestedfile=context.Request.QueryString["file"];
    if(!File.Exists(Server.MapPath(requestedfile)))
         {
         //write error status code telling them the file doesn't exist. Probably a 404 error.
         context.Response.End();
         }

    if(HasAccess(context.User.Identity.Name, requestedfile))
       {
       //write the file to the response
       context.Response.ContentType= "";//replace with MIME type of requested file
       context.Response.WriteFile(context.Server.MapPath(requestedfile));
       context.Response.End();
       }
    else
       {
        //return error status code telling them they're unauthorized
        context.Response.End();
        }
    }

public static bool HasAccess(string username, string file)
    {
    //if user has access to the file, return true. Else return false. This might involve database lookups etc
    }
```

The real magic is going to happen in the `HasAccess` function where you'll have to implement your checks to make sure they're authorized to access the file. All the other stuff is just handling common things like forgetting to specify the file or specifying an invalid file.

User then accesses a file by requesting this url: `mysite.com/FileRetriever.ashx?file=path/to/document/document.pdf`

Comment: I can't expect people to enter a username. If I assume that everyone is authorized, can I skip the part where they ask for the username and simply deliver the content via FileRetriever.ashx?

Comment: We never asked the user to enter a username. We're pulling that from the `context.User.Identity.Name` property available from the `HttpContext`. This assumes the user has logged into your site. And like I said in the comment on your question, users are NOT AUTHORIZED if they're trying to access a file they shouldn't have access to. Therefore, everyone is NOT AUTHORIZED for every document. Only *some* users are authorized for *some documents*.

Comment: Right click your web application project or web site. Go to Add New Item. Select your language (C#) and then under Web you should see a Generic Handler item. Name it `FileRetriever.ashx`. I'm not going to provide a link because I'd have to Google for one and there's no reason you can't do that yourself.

Comment: Yeah I still don't think this is the way to go. The files are not present on the same machine as the web site, plain and simple. The HttpContext doesn't get any of the information about the files. The files are searched in a mapped drive on a remote machine and then stored in a string builder that is then output through a literal inside a panel. When you click a link to those files you go COMPLETELY outside my website to the website of where they're actually stored, however, that website has a piece of URL that I do not want people to see. I'm starting to think it really isn't possible.

Comment: You should have explain the full limitations in your question. My solution is perfectly suited to running on the server that actually serves the documents, and you should implement it there.

Answer (score -1):

You should never and i emphasize **ever** have sensitive files exposed to the web. Not knowing the url is not a security/authentication method. All the files you wish to protect should live outside of IIS/Web and need to be retrieved and served by your application. The application would control access to the files based on some level of authorization.

The reason for this as it has been seen in many large companies such as AT&T it takes one user to brute force all links on your site and obtain all your employee information just by trying different url combinations. Do not go down this road.

Comment: Where exactly do you answer the question? That's more like a lenghty comment